# Ios Design through Ui Code

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, scrollview, landscape

***How to set ScrollView in xamarin ios in landscape mode through UI code in c#??

Please send me Practically As I am new in Xamarin Ios***

I have tried xamarin tutorial scrollview but it didn't work for me.

This  is my Source code

```
public class CustomViewController : UIViewController
{
      UITextField usernameField, passwordField, firstnamefield, lastnamefield, confirmpasswordField;
      UILabel lblfirstname, lblLastname, lblPassword, lblConfirmPassword;
     nfloat LableWidth = 90;
    // UIScrollView scrollView;

    public CustomViewController()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        nfloat h = 31.0f;
        nfloat w = (View.Bounds.Width);
        nfloat topgap = 15, leftgap = 10, rightgap = 10, topposition = 90;


        #region First Name
        lblfirstname = new UILabel
        {
            Text = "First Name",
            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap, topposition, LableWidth, h),

        };
        //First Name
        firstnamefield = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter your firstname",

            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,
            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap + LableWidth, topposition, w - 20 - LableWidth, h),
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            // AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.,
        };
        #endregion

        topposition = (topposition + h + topgap);
        #region Last Name
        lblLastname = new UILabel
        {
            Text = "Last Name",
            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap, topposition, LableWidth, h)
        };

        lastnamefield = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter your lastname",
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,
            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap + LableWidth, topposition, w - 20 - LableWidth, h),
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            // AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.,

        };
        #endregion

        topposition = (topposition + h + topgap);
        #region Password
        lblPassword = new UILabel
        {
            Text = "Password",
            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap, topposition, LableWidth, h)
        };

        passwordField = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter your password",
            BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,
            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap + LableWidth, topposition, w - 20 - LableWidth, h),
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            SecureTextEntry = true

        };
        #endregion

        topposition = (topposition + h + topgap);
        #region Confirm Password

        lblConfirmPassword = new UILabel
        {
            Text = "Confirm Password",

            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap, topposition, LableWidth, h)
        };

        confirmpasswordField = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter your confirm password",
            BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,
            Frame = new CGRect(leftgap + LableWidth, topposition, w - 20 - LableWidth, h),
            SecureTextEntry = true,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            //AutoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight,
        };
        #endregion

        nfloat genderWidth = 80, Gleft = (View.Bounds.Width - genderWidth * 2) / 2;


        topposition = (topposition + h + topgap);
        var malebutton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        malebutton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        malebutton.Frame = new CGRect(Gleft, topposition, genderWidth, 44);
        malebutton.SetTitle("Male", UIControlState.Normal);

        malebutton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Submit button pressed");                
            malebutton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Brown, UIControlState.Normal);
            malebutton.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
        };


        //    topposition = (topposition + h + topgap);
        var femalebutton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        femalebutton.Frame = new CGRect(Gleft + genderWidth, topposition, genderWidth, 44);
        femalebutton.SetTitle("FEMALE", UIControlState.Normal);
        femalebutton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

        femalebutton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Submit button pressed");


            femalebutton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Brown, UIControlState.Normal);
            femalebutton.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;

        };

        topposition = (topposition + h + topgap);
        var submitButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);

        submitButton.Frame = new CGRect(10, topposition, w - 20, 44);
        submitButton.SetTitle("Submit", UIControlState.Normal);

        submitButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Submit button pressed");
            Signup();
            submitButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            submitButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
            // AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
        };
        // scroll.ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Bounds.Width,topposition+50);

        View.AddSubviews(new UIView[] { confirmpasswordField, lastnamefield, firstnamefield, passwordField, malebutton, lblfirstname, submitButton, femalebutton, lblLastname, lblPassword, lblConfirmPassword });
       // View.AddSubview(scrollView);
    }
```

Comment: Share your source code

Comment: I have added my  Source code

Comment: Your scrollView is commented in your code. You should put the scrollView inside the ViewController's view and others views inside the scrollView

Comment: I have added that  but it didn't work

Comment: Compare carefully your code eith the scrollView added and the guide One, maybe you forgot something. Anyway update your question by adding link to the guide and your source code when using scrollView